# Select max value of column before a different value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's pretend I have this table on a MySQL database called 'Relocations', which I keep track of all relocations of an user in an appointment:

```
UserId AppointmentTypeId  History   Location   Time
------------------------------------------------------
[ 1    1                  1        'Room A'   13:00 ]
  1    1                  2        'Room B'   13:01
[ 1    1                  3        'Room A'   13:02 ]
  1    1                  4        'Room C'   13:03
  1    1                  5        'Room D'   13:05
[ 1    1                  6        'Room A'   13:09 ]
  2    1                  1        'Room A'   13:00
[ 2    1                  2        'Room A'   13:05 ]
  2    1                  3        'Room B'   13:10
```

I need to get all the rows where Location = 'Room A', but only those whose next row is Location != 'Room A' and UserId and AppointmentTypeId are the same.

So I would get, from this table, the rows that are inside brackets.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is history always sequential +1 for each change? or could you have gaps that you need to manage?  Also what version of mySQL does it support Analytical functions such as lead() or Lag()?

Comment: @xQbert historycount is always sequential - there are no gaps. prod server tells me that it's running mysql 5.5.43-ubuntu-12.04.1

Comment: if it's always sequential then I think Gordon has a good solution.  That version doesn't support window/analytical functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a convenient `history` column, so use a `left join`:

```
select r.*
from relocations r left join
     relocations rnext
     on rnext.userid = r.userid and rnext.AppointmentTypeId = r.AppointmentTypeId and
        rnext.history = r.history + 1
where r.Location = 'Room A' and
      (rnext.Location <> 'Room A' or rnext.Location is null);
```